# Why is $\pi_* MU$ concentrated in even degrees?

Tags: algebraic-topology

$\pi_* MU$, which is the cobordism ring of manifolds with a complex structure on the stable normal bundle, is a polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_2, x_4, \dots]$. I'm probably being silly here, but is there some obvious reason why everything is in even degrees? Is it obvious that an odd-dimensional manifold whose normal bundle in some imbedding gets a complex structure is cobordant to zero? (For that matter, is it even obvious that such a manifold is unorientedly cobordant to zero?)

Comment: One could identify the E_2 term of the Adams spectral sequence, but I think you are looking for a simpler/more geometric answer. I haven't spent much time thinking about MU in terms of cobordism, so I am very curious to see an answer to this question.

Comment: I don't think there is a mathematical reason (aka easy proof), only some "philosophical" (aka unconvincing) ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think either result is "obvious" geometrically. As Grigory says, it is somehow morally true. Here is what I understand of this part of the story:

1. You can prove directly from Thom's isomorphism between complex cobordism and $\pi_*MU$ together with some Serre mod C stuff that $MU_* \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is concentrated in even degrees (you can even get the multiplicative structure pretty easily). As a consequence one gets that every odd-dimensional complex manifold becomes null-bordant (in the complex sense) after taking disjoint unions enough times. Is there a way to do this geometrically? I'd love to see it!
2. If you want an *almost* purely geometric proof that the odd parts vanish, see Quillen's paper "Elementary proofs of some results of cobordism theory using Steenrod operations" (it's awesome) Corollary 5.2. Again- it doesn't seem too obvious.
3. If you already know everything about unoriented cobordism, then it is easy (I hate to call anything obvious) to show that any odd-dimensional stably complex manifold is null-bordant. Proof: By the basic result, we need only check that the Stiefel-Whitney numbers are all zero. But when we compute a Stiefel-Whitney number, we'll have to use  a product of Stiefel-Whitney classes where at least one of the Stiefel-Whitney classes lives in odd degree. But these are all zero; the proof of this I leave as an exercise.
4. Another reason why this is non-obvious: Every framed manifold is canonically stably complex and so we have a "forgetful" map $\pi_*S \rightarrow MU_*$ (it's the same as the Hurewicz map). Now, we happen to know that the image of this map is zero in positive dimensions, since $\pi_kS$ is torsion for $k>0$, and if we also knew that $MU_*$ was torsion-free we'd conclude that every positive-dimensional framed manifold bounds a stably complex one. Now, this is probably just my ignorance, but I have no idea how to prove this geometrically. So, for example, take some odd-dimensional class in $\pi_*S$ lying in the kernel of $\pi_*S \rightarrow \pi_*MO$ (this is basically to rule out stuff generated by Hopf invariant elements).

Anyway, maybe this doesn't answer your question... and maybe the answer is yes and *I'm* just being silly... but I should really go to bed.

Comment: (I should mention I purposefully avoided mentioning anything about the Steenrod algebra or Adams spectral sequence... because once you do that- you may as well just calculate the whole thing. Everything collapses anyway.)

Comment: Thanks! This is very nice (and you're right, I was being silly about the unoriented part of it). The paper by Quillen sounds fun. Incidentally, do you know where the usual proof via the Adams spectral sequence of $\pi_*MU$ (that it is the Lazard ring, not just a polynomial ring) was done? Everyone keeps pointing to Adams's blue book.

Comment: Of course any polynomial ring like that "is" the Lazard ring :) But showing the formal group law of $\pi_*MU$ is the universal one... That was originally announced by Quillen in "On the formal group laws of unoriented and complex cobordism theory," so I imagine the first way he figured out how to prove this was by knowing the computation of $\pi_*MU$ already, and then showing some stuff commuted. But his published proof was the elementary one. The references I know of that use the ASS + formal group theory are Adams book and Ravenel's book.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant -- I had seen Quillen's original paper where he announced it but was surprised I couldn't find a proof in the literature. I've never looked at Ravenel's book, perhaps I should.

Comment: Basically the proof goes like this: (1) Identify the Lazard ring $L$ and its relationship to a ring $M \subset L \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ using formal group law stuff. (2) Identify $\pi_*MU$ and its relationship to $H_*MU$ using homotopy theory. (3) Construct a commutative square that says the relationship between the corresponding rings is (basically) what you think and use it to show the map you want is an isomorphism.

Comment: But yeah- look in Ravenel, he does it well.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the argument in Lurie's "chromatic" lecture notes and pretend to understand it at parties, but I certainly need to spend more time trying to understand this stuff.

Comment: Sounds like you go to some fun parties! (I'm not even being sarcastic)

Comment: Heh, I wish! (Sarcasm in print doesn't always work well.) At some point I'll have to ask you for a reading list for this stuff (more basic than the sources you mentioned on MO).

Answer (score 5):

According to Peter May's [Stable Algebraic Topology 1945-1966](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0321/history.pdf)

```
...there is no known geometric reason why the 
complex cobordism ring should be concentrated in even degree
```

(This is on page 23)

So really, as others have alluded to, I guess this is just an algebraic result. It would be interesting to find some geometric meaning behind it!

Comment: This article is really nice, by the way.

Comment: I agree! I found it originally in I.M. James' [History of Topology](http://www.amazon.com/History-Topology-I-M-James/dp/0444823751)